# Key error: "PNG" while using pytesseract python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Even though I followed the question [KeyError: 'PNG' while using pytesseract.image_to_data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038499/keyerror-png-while-using-pytesseract-image-to-data), I couldn't resolve the problem.

1. I installed the tesseract in google colab.

   ```
   !sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
   ```
2. then installed pytesseract=0.3.9

   ```
   !pip install pytesseract==0.3.9
   ```
3. this is my code:

   ```
    import cv2
    from pytesseract import Output
    from PIL import Image
    import pytesseract

    image = cv2.imread('0003.jpg')
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)
   ```

but I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-21a4d6775e8a> in <module>
      9 image = cv2.imread('/content/sample_data/0003.jpg')
     10 rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
---> 11 results = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)
     12 for i in range(0, len(results["text"])):
     13     x = results["left"][i]

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2121         expand=0,
   2122         center=None,
-> 2123         translate=None,
   2124         fillcolor=None,
   2125     ):

KeyError: 'PNG'
```

Comment: Hello! Is `0003.jpg` a valid file inside you colab workspace?

Comment: yes it works . Also I compiled the same code in kaggle. It works there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicate your situation on my system(google colab) and it works perfectly.

Apart from that, your code is perfectly fine. no bug at all.

I think there is a version issue. You try this version of cv2

```
cv2 version: 4.6.0
```

Make sure the image you fetch it should be image.jpg

or

You can upload image and use image path instead of image name.

```
 import cv2
 from pytesseract import Output
 from PIL import Image
 import pytesseract

 image = cv2.imread('/content/0001.jpg') # here i use path instead of image name
 rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 results = pytesseract.image_to_data(rgb, output_type=Output.DICT)
 print(results.keys())
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.:) I have checked the version, it's 4.6.0.  Also as you said I ensured that I have fetched the appropriate file format (image.jpg), also used the complete path. But still, I get the same error.

Comment: in google colab  go to Runtime  and  select Restart Runtime. See if it work.

Comment: yea when I restart the runtime it works. please add this as a NOTE:, some people like me would ignore this step. So that will accept your answer. Thank you for spending time on this question. :)