# Cannot read an image inside a PDF using PyMUpdf and pytesseract

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract, pymupdf

This is my code:

```py
import fitz
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

# Open the PDF file using PyMuPDF
pdf_file = fitz.open("file")

# Iterate through all the pages in the PDF

text_list = []

for page_number in range(pdf_file.page_count):
    page = pdf_file[page_number]
    images = pdf_file.get_page_images(page_number)
    
    # Iterate through all the images in the page
    for img in images:
        xref = img[0]
        pix = fitz.Pixmap(pdf_file, xref)
        
        # Check if the image is RGB or RGBA
        if pix.n >= 3:
            image = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
        else:
            image = Image.frombytes("L", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)

        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
        text_list.append(text)

df = pd.DataFrame(text_list)

print(df)
```

This is the error I get:

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-a9f3c12268ea> in <module>
     25             image = Image.frombytes("L", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
     26 
---> 27         text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
     28         text_list.append(text)
     29 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2121         """
   2122 
-> 2123         if resample is None:
   2124             type_special = ";" in self.mode
   2125             resample = Resampling.NEAREST if type_special else Resampling.BICUBIC

KeyError: 'PNG'
```

For more info, this is the table I'm trying to read (in the PDF file): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pH93Ax4fsiPlq7KNtAAOpKuuGcoupHQ3/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Check your `pytesseract` version. Ensure your PDF are truly rendered as image. 
 Perhaps these two might assist
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811738/key-error-png-while-using-pytesseract-python | 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038499/keyerror-png-while-using-pytesseract-image-to-data

Comment: An image also may be CMYK (neither RGB nor GRAY)